# how to write 8 bytes to a void * address?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, data-structures

So I have a defined a 8 bytes data structure

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) entry{
    // something here total 64 bits;
}entry_t;
```

and I have a `void* base`which is a pointer pointing to the base of where I want to put the entry.

Will

```
entry_t a;
*base = a;
```

do the job?

or I have to cast base to pointer to `entry_t`?

**UPDATE**
Sorry I didn't mention I can't use memcpy, because the kernel I am using doesn't implement memcpy yet.

Comment: Are you sure the bytes after the *byte* `base` points to are free?

Comment: Why does base need to be a `void*`?

Comment: @Jefffrey _free_ what? What means _free_????

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, not used by other objects?

Comment: @Jefffrey: Timothy says that `base` points to a space where he want to store the 8 bytes, so presumably, all the 8 bytes can legitimately be assigned.

Comment: @Jefffrey Ah ha! Suppose the address is pointing to some mapped peripheral register access, which objects?? Elaborate ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the fact that he *wants* to store something, doesn't mean it has the necessary space for it. I would also be very curious as to how he got this certainty that 64 bits are free.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you know exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Jefffrey **Me and you know** of course, does the OP?

Comment: Actually I am writing a new entry to the IDT, the base is pointing to the position of the entry.

Comment: _"because the kernel I am using doesn't implement memcpy"_ Sounds strange because it's very basic [tag:c] (newlib) functionality, I can hardly believe this. But anyway a straight forward implementation for `memcpy()` should be pretty trivial!

Comment: have you considered writing a small piece of inline assembly ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, also technically speaking the memory model of C++ is platform indipendent. When I say *object* I talk about the definition of *object* that the Standard specifies in §1.7.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, of course he does. Why wouldn't he? Did he reply confused somehow? Do you have any proof that he does not understand what I'm saying? (and if he doesn't I'll happily clear his doubts).

Comment: @Jefffrey Having a closer look, I agree: The OP knows (that making the question a bit pointless then ;-) ).

Comment: Odd question, considering that `*base = a;` will never compile. You can;t de-reference an incomplete type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either:

```
*((entry_t *)base) = a;
```

or

```
memcpy(base, &a, sizeof a);
```

Of course, make sure that there are in fact 8 bytes there to copy into.

Comment: Looked more like C to me than C++.

Comment: sizeof is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, [absolutely](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da46680dcc7b5b99).

Comment: There are times when `sizeof(argument)` requires the parenthesis; there is never a time when `sizeof(argument)` yields the wrong result.  Ergo, it is simplest to treat it uniformly and use parentheses.

Comment: Jeff's example is also C++, a language I have no use for. The original questioner might want to clarify which language he's interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the pointer to `unsigned char *` and write the 8 bytes with 8 uses of the assignment operator (either in a loop, or unrolled).